Storybook overwrite imported constant
The React component, I write a story for, looks like this:
import { SHOW_ERRORS } from './env.js';

export const ErrorList = React.memo((): JSX.Element | null => {
  return SHOW_ERRORS ? <p>Errors...</p> : null;
});

My Storybook story looks like this:
import type { Meta, StoryObj } from '@storybook/react';
import { ErrorList } from './MappingError.js';

const meta: Meta<typeof ErrorList> = {
  title: 'ErrorList',
  component: ErrorList,
};

export default meta;
type Story = StoryObj<typeof ErrorList>;

export const Default: Story = {};

Is there a way to change / mock SHOW_ERRORS from within the story?

Ok, seems like an actual bug: https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/17336
But when it's ok to set them globally, use in your Storybook config:
define: {
  process: {
    env: {
      SHOW_ERRORS: 1,
    },
  },
},

